# Excel dynamic tables like functionality in web application

Tags: excel

I need a way to show a grid in a web application, allowing grouping of the data by several user selected fields. The ideal would be something like what excel dynamic tables provide. Does anyone know about a control that can do this?  If it is integrated with ASP.NET that would be a plus.
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Ext](http://extjs.com/). It's a JavaScript library which (amongst other things) can be used to display a sortable/filterable list. It all happens on the client, so it's very lightweight from a server perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [Grid example from EXtJs](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grouping.html) with grouping.